# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me cierre sesion (login) al retroceder desde cualquier navegador?

Tags: php, html

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que al retroceder a la pagina anterior no me genere este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me sale cuando voy a iniciar sesion y quiero retroceder desde la flecha de arriba a la izquierda, esto me sucede cuando voy a otro hipervinculo y retrocedo, siempre me sale este error, quisiera saber como puedo solucionarlo y que pueda retroceder sin que me salga aquel error

Por aqui el codigo del login y el navbar:

Login:

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/ICONO.png">
</head>
<!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Bon Appetit - Ingresar</title>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid ml-auto">
        <a class="navbar-brand titulo" href="#">Bonappetit</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navcolor" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="../index.php">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="platillos.php">Platillos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="resena.php">Reseña</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contactanos.php">Contactanos</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="forms">
        <div class="form login">
            <span class="title">Inicia Sesión</span>

            <form action="validar_login.php" method="post">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" required name="Usuario">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required name="Contrasena">
                    <i class="uil uil-eye-slash showHidePw"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox-text">
                  
                    <a href="#" class="text">Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                </div>

                    <button class="buttonI">Ingresar</button>
            </form>

            <div class="login-signup">
                <span class="text">Todavia no tienes una cuenta?
                    <a href="registrate.php" class="text signup-link">Ingresar</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include("../template/footer.php") ?>
```

Este es el del navbar que me permite mantener la sesion siempre y cuando vaya a cualquier pagina mas no cuando retrocedo:

```
<?php
    // No mostrar los errores de PHP
    error_reporting(0);

    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Clicker+Script&family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid ml-auto">
        <a class="navbar-brand titulo" href="#">Bonappetit</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <!--Despues de logearse-->
    <?php
        //En el if va la variable con la que identificas si estan logueados
        if($_SESSION['usuario'] == true){
    ?>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navcolor" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="platillos.php">Platillos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="resena.php">Reseña</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="reservas.php">Reserva</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contactanos.php">Contactanos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                   <b>Hola</b>, <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="editar_usuario.php">Editar</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="cerrar_sesion.php">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
        </div>

    <?php
        //Acción que se ejecutaria en caso de que no estes logueado
        }else{
    ?>
    <!--Antes de logearse-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navcolor" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../view/platillos.php">Platillos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../view/resena.php">Reseña</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../view/contactanos.php">Contactanos</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../view/login.php">Ingresar</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="../view/registrate.php">Registrate</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues utilizando `method="get"` en vez de `method="post"` en la etiqueta `<form>`.

Ese aviso te aparece para evitar que reenvíes datos u ordenes cosas por duplicado. En aplicaciones web no deberías utilizar el botón `Atrás` del navegador, sino utilizar los enlaces y botones que el desarrollador haya dejado disponibles, precisamente para evitar lo que el mensaje que quieres ocultar indica.